# Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated on Laravel 5.5 and php 7.1.11

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, php-7.1

I have upgraded laravel 5.3 to laravel 5.5 and I am using php 7.1.11

On upgrading I am getting error

`ErrorException (E_ERROR) Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated`

In `config\app` I have

```
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'
```

Also try adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

to it but still getting error.

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, self::$skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
```

This is code where I am using it.

Comment: Yes the function is deprecated as of PHP 7.1.0 as you [can see here](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.mcrypt-get-iv-size.php), thus you could change it and use something else to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Will it work on 7.0 ? @JulienLachal

Comment: What is alternative?

Comment: Alternative is a proposition or situation offering a choice between two or more things only one of which may be chosen

Comment: Yes it will work on 7.0 but as the documentation says you really shouldn't. It's deprecated for a reason,.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has removed any mcrypt code in 5.3 (it was not used by default since Laravel 5.1) so I'm assuming this is OPs own code.

Ideally this code should be migrated to OpenSSL but until this happens it can be wrapped like so:

```
$olderrorReporting = error_reporting();
error_reporting($olderrorReporting&(~E_DEPRECATED));
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, self::$skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
error_reporting($olderrorReporting)
```

The above solution can be used to "suppress" deprecated warnings in general.

Sidenote: `$a ^ $b` is XOR in PHP so `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED)` is basically equivalent to `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Answer (score -1):

you can check this
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16329
or
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16884 (my problem solved with this link - for Laravel 4.2)